# MySQL syntax error, about union and as keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select distinct id, item from 
(
    (
        (
            select ID as id, "INNER" as item 
            from TREE 
            where ID in 
            (
                select P_ID from TREE as T1
            )  
            and P_ID is not null
        ) 
        as T3
    )
    union
    (
        (
            select ID as id, "ROOT" as item 
            from TREE 
            where P_ID IS NULL
        ) 
        as T2
    )
)
```

The TREE table has structure like this:

```
ID, P_ID
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

I am a noob in SQL and I really don't know why there is always problem when I am executing it.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'as T2  ) )' at line 22

Could you tell me? Thanks!

Comment: Too much *brackets*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what you are trying to achieve from query but fix the syntax error you can rewrite your query as

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  id,
  item 
FROM(
  SELECT 
    ID AS id,
    "INNER" AS item 
  FROM
    TREE 
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT P_ID FROM TREE) 
  AND P_ID IS NOT NULL 

  UNION

  SELECT 
    ID AS id,
    "ROOT" AS item 
  FROM
    TREE 
  WHERE P_ID IS NULL
) as t
```

Comment: There is an error telling me `every derived table must have its own alias`.

Comment: @DavidLee answer updated you need to give alias for sub select like `) as t`